# Reports get wrong links and cannot be found in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, reporting, code-coverage, dox, php-code-coverage

In the `build.xml` of my Jenkins (PHP) project (hosted on a Windows Server) multiple reports are defined (*PMD Warnings, Duplicate Code, JDepend, Checkstyle Warnings, Coverage Summary Report, PHPUnit_Code_Coverage, PHPDox*). All the needed plug-ins are installed and the links of the most of the reports in the menu and on the dashboard

[image]

lead to the appropriate report pages.

Only two links (PHPUnit Code Coverage and PHPDox) don't work and show a `404` page:

[image]

Though they seem to be set correctly:

[image: Jenkins - project settings - Publish HTML reports]

[image: Jenkins MyProject workspace]

**Why does this issue occurs and how to make Jenkins add the reports correctly to the project's menu/dashboard?**

Comment: did your last build/current build run successfully?

Comment: Yes, the build ran successfully.